# deleting rows using Ajax/jQuery in rails, something is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is fairly straight forward code but somehow when I click on 'delete' the record get deleted but it doesn't get shown on the index page until I refresh it. I am using jquery to show all the records.

in controller, I have added in the destroy action

```
format.js
```

in Index.html.erb, I have added

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true %></td>
```

in destroy.js.erb, I have added

```
$('#edit_post_<%= @post.id %>').remove();
```

Now when I click on the delete link, the post gets deleted but the output of index file Doesn't get updated and only when I refresh it, it shows the new list without the deleted item. Any idea what am I missing ?

Thanks

EDIT - Ok, I was able to solve this, the problem was bad jquery code in destroy.js.erb, I was calling the wrong div

Comment: If you watch your network tab in developer tools, are you getting a response from the server? Is it sending you the javascript you're expecting?

Comment: Does your action "destroy" process as JS ? You can see it in your server console, example on my machine: `Started GET "/settings/computed_labs.yaml" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-03 12:01:50 -0500
Processing by Settings::ComputedLabsController#index as YAML`

Comment: **it shows the new list without the deleted item** is this not deleted with click of the deleted link?

Comment: @chrisbulmer - under network, it is getting post/xx with 200 OK

Comment: @MrYoshiji - I am not very sure what are you saying, can you please clarify ?

Comment: @Jai - the item is getting deleted but it is not getting reflexted in index.html.erb, when I refresh it, only then the item gets stop showing though it is getting deleted from the database

Answer (score 0):

At controller set this
 `@post_id = @post.id`
before you destroy post.

And at js.erb file use this line 
    `$('#edit_post_<%= @post_id %>').remove();`

Because after delete the post, @post.id does not mean anything in js file.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't worked, the post is getting deleted, but it is not getting removed from the list unless I refresh it

Answer (score 0):

please be sure you have added `@post.destroy` method in your controller before rendering `format.js` . Currently you  are only removing  from html source . To reflect changes you must change value overall ( from `database`)